# Iterating over all combinations of an binary array without saving values of array python

Tags: python, arrays, storage, combinations

I am trying to iterate over all combinations of a binary array (e.g. [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1], ... [1,1,1,1]) without generating a list containing all combinations since the binary array contains more than 40 elements (so more than 2^40 combinations).

What I am currently doing:

```
for i in range(2**(len(binaryArray))):
        b = decimal_in_binary_array(i, len(binaryArray))
        #do sth with b
```

This works fine, but converting the decimal value into a binary array takes time.

```
def decimal_in_binary_array(decimal, array_length):
    a = [int(x) for x in bin(decimal)[2:]]
    a = [0]*(array_length-len(a)) + a
    return a
```

I already tried using

1. itertools.permutations
2. multiset_permutations from scypy

However, itertools does not recognize same values.
And for both versions I first need to generate a list with all combinations which is not possible for such a large number of combinations.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify, does your code work fine but you would like to know if there's a better way of doing it using `itertools.permutations` or `multiset_permutations`?

Comment: You can use recursion.

Comment: I would like to speed up the code, so I want to avoid transforming the decimal into a binary array each time. I tried itertools.permutations and multiset_permutations but it seems not to work. My computer crashes. I think it takes up too much storage to create all combinations in a list? But not sure about that